# spritekit: unable to detect collision

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

so i tried to use skphysicscontact but when the "cat" and "spinnynode" collides there is no output from them, even when there is physical interaction

on another note, why can't the timer function work? it doesn't seem to call out the function at all.

please help, I'm a newbie. Thanks

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct physicsCollision {
static let cat: UInt32 = 1
static let spinnyNode: UInt32 = 2
}



class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {



var entities = [GKEntity]()
var graphs = [String : GKGraph]()
var catTimer = Timer()
var score = 0


private var lastUpdateTime : TimeInterval = 0
private var label : SKLabelNode?
private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?




let meow = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("cat meow", waitForCompletion: false)



required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

//random range 

func randomInRange(lo: Float, hi : Float) -> Float{
    return lo + Float(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hi - lo + 1)))
}


//spawn cat

func spawnCat(){

    // x coordinate between MinX (left) and MaxX (right):
    let randomX = randomInRange(lo: Float(self.frame.minX + 5), hi: Float(self.frame.maxX + 5))

    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomX), y: self.frame.height * 1.2)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomX), y:self.frame.height * -0.5)
    let cat = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "before right")

    cat.name = "cat"
    cat.setScale(0.3)
    cat.position = startPoint
    cat.zPosition = 1
    cat.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: cat.size.width, height: cat.size.height))
    cat.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    cat.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCollision.cat
    cat.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCollision.spinnyNode
    cat.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCollision.spinnyNode
    cat.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    self.addChild(cat)

    let moveCat = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 5)
    let deleteCat = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let catSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveCat, meow, deleteCat])
    cat.run(catSequence)


}

//contact func

func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact){

    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "cat"
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }
    else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
 if firstBody.node?.name == "cat" && (secondBody.node?.name)! == "skinnynode"{
    print("contacted")

    }
}


override func sceneDidLoad() {

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    self.lastUpdateTime = 0

    //spawn cat at intervals,, time interval to decrease when points increase, use if loop


    catTimer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1 , target: self, selector: Selector(("cat")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



    // Create shape node to use during mouse interaction
    let w = (self.size.width + self.size.height) * 0.05
    self.spinnyNode = SKShapeNode.init(rectOf: CGSize.init(width: w, height: w), cornerRadius: w * 0.5)
    spinnyNode?.name = "spinnynode"
    spinnyNode?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 0.5)
    spinnyNode?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    spinnyNode?.zPosition = 1
    spinnyNode?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCollision.spinnyNode
    if let spinnyNode = self.spinnyNode{
        spinnyNode.lineWidth = 1.5
        spinnyNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), duration: 1)))
        spinnyNode.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5),
                                          SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.3),
                                          SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
                                        }

    //create score label
    let scoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:((self.frame.height) * 0.5) , y:((self.frame.width) * 0.3), width: (self.frame.size.width)/3, height: 30))
    scoreLabel.center = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.size.width)/1.6 , y: (self.frame.size.height)/2)
    scoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    self.view?.addSubview(scoreLabel)



                                }


func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    if let n = self.spinnyNode?.copy() as! SKShapeNode? {
        n.position = pos
        n.strokeColor = SKColor.green
        self.addChild(n)
    }
}

func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    if let n = self.spinnyNode?.copy() as! SKShapeNode? {
        n.position = pos
        n.strokeColor = SKColor.purple
        self.addChild(n)

    }
}

func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    if let n = self.spinnyNode?.copy() as! SKShapeNode? {
        n.position = pos
        n.strokeColor = SKColor.red
        self.addChild(n)
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            spawnCat()
            if let label = self.label {
            label.run(SKAction.init(named: "Pulse")!, withKey: "fadeInOut")

    }

    for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered

    // Initialize _lastUpdateTime if it has not already been
    if (self.lastUpdateTime == 0) {
        self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    }

    // Calculate time since last update
    let dt = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTime

    // Update entities
    for entity in self.entities {
        entity.update(deltaTime: dt)
    }

    self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime
}
```

}

Comment: something to make your life a bit easier: `cat.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: cat.size)`

Answer (score 2):

You spelled the function wrong. It is never getting called. This is the correct protocol function name:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
  // Your stuff here..
}
```

You can use autocomplete to avoid this problem. Start typing "didbegin" and you will have Xcode fill out the correct function:

[image]

---

As an aside:

Also, you are using hardcoded strings which can cause problems later on. Perhaps you could try using a constant value or a struct to avoid potential future spelling mistakes in strings:

```
let names = (cat: "cat", spinnynode: "spinnynode")

// cat.name = names.cat, etc...

func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact){
  // ...
  if contact.bodyA.node?.name == names.cat
  {
    firstBody = contact.bodyA
    secondBody = contact.bodyB
  }
  else{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB
    secondBody = contact.bodyA
  }

  if firstBody.node?.name == names.cat && secondBody.node!.name == names.spinnynode {
    print("contacted")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `categoryBitMask` method of the SKPhysicsContactDelegate? You may be able to fix your issue by going into the GameScene.sks file and assigning the `Category Mask` to a number other than the default. Do this for both of your bodies, but assign different values for each of the bodies. [image: example blocks showing category mask identification number other than default]

Then, inside your GameScene.swift, your `didBegin` contact function might look something like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

//set these values to the same number in your GameScene.sks file
let catCategory = 2
let skinnyNodeCategory = 3

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let bodyA = contact.bodyA
    let bodyB = contact.bodyB

    //check to see if the bodies in contact match
    //the category mask numbers you defined
    //here the conditional is set to say that either of the bodies
    //in contact match the categoryBitMask number set in the GameScene.sks file

    //using && may not work depending on how the categoryBitMask identifiers 
    //are assigned by the physicsContactDelegate

    if bodyA.categoryBitMask == catCategory || bodyB.categoryBitMask == catCategory {

        print("contacted")

        }
    }
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: your categories need to be multiples of two (2, 4, 8, 16, etc), otherwise you will register incorrect hits with more than two categories :)

Comment: Also, your categories need to be `UInt32`